# SQL Group By vs. UDT Parameters Processed via Cursor/Loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, group-by, user-defined-types

My current `SELECT` statement has this clause:

```
 GROUP BY MeasurableID, EntityID
```

For various reasons I am instead considering passing into the query a UserDefinedTable pre-populated with all possible "groups" (i.e. The SELECT . . . GROUP BY would be sent to the web client then sent back -- with other parameters -- to a stored procedure that would loop through them.

More specifically, if the output of the Group By was a table with MeasurableID values 1, 1, 2 and EntityID values A, B, A then the loop would be for each of "1 & A"; "1 & B"; "2 & A";    )

Is the only/best way to process this via a Cursor/Loop through the UDT?

(As a PS is this such a Cursor/Loop likely to perform better or worse than a Group By?  Intuitively to me the loop is much less work though perhaps indexing allows the db engine to infer from previous groups)

Comment: What do you mean by "all possible groupings"?

Comment: @ZLK I edited question to clarify, thanks.

Comment: describe your problem, not your attempt to solve it. Add table structure, data sample, and expected results. Preferably, a scipt for creating and populating tables.

Comment: Without knowing the problem you're trying to solve, generally it's better not to try and out-smart the database. If you're trying to mimic a GROUP BY by generating data in the client and sending it to the stored procedure, it may perform worse. And it sounds complex. But as mentioned by Horaciux - what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and I understand your points but the code is quite complicated to post (I tried making a SQLfiddle example but failed due to size limitations).  Also this forum is much more focused on completing code than I realize this more theoretical question is aimed at.  Basically I just wanted to be forewarned if any major reason existed not to consider the strategy above, which fwiw is basically trying to solve a current problem where a CROSS JOIN takes 90-120 seconds to complete.